# Jest test in Expo rising error [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo, asyncstorage

I am getting the error of [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null. once I am trying to run tests in my typescript expo project.

I followed the steps in [here](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest/)  but afterwards I am getting the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Ensure `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` is installed and linked.

  2 | import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
  3 | import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";
> 4 | import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth";
    | ^
  5 | import { post } from "aws-amplify/api";
  6 | import {
  7 |   GestureHandlerRootView,
```

The linking should be handled automatically. my test:

```js
it("renders correctly", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<UserCard />);
  const element = getByText("Greetings!");
  expect(element).toBeTruthy();
});
```

my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "amplify-graphql-prework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|@expo/vector-icons)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetupFile.ts"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/react-native": "^1.0.5",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.1.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.5",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```